# template of template syntax

Tags: c++, templates

I am at a bit of a loss with templates of templates.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Foo{
    T foobar;
    T getFooBar();
};

template <class T>
T Foo<T>::getFooBar(){
    return (T) 2.0;
}

template <class T, template<class> class H>
class Bar{
    void barbar();
};

template <class T, template<class> class H>
void Bar<T, H<T> >::barbar(){}

int main(int iargc, char *iargv[]){
    // do stuff;
}
```

This does not compile and I do not understand the error message of the compiler

```
expected a class template, got ‘H<T>’
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? `H<T>` is a class, not a class template

Comment: I want to have a class constructed from a template as template argument.

Comment: Bar has two template parameters, one is a type (like int) and one is a class template (like Foo). You can say `Bar<int, Foo>`. You can never ever say `Bar<int, Foo<int>>`, in any context, it just makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax would be to just pass `H`:

```
template <class T, template<class> class H>
void Bar<T, H>::barbar() {}
            ^^
```

`H<T>` is a concrete type, `H` by itself is the class template you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`H<T>` is itself a type, so you don't need to prefix `template<class>` to the template parameter for `Bar`.

Here is a simplified example:

```
template<class A>
class T1 {
    A a;    
};

template<class B>
class T2 {
    B a;
};

class T3 {
    T1<T2<int> > example;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define the member function `barbar()`, you should

```
template <class T, template<class> class H>
void Bar<T, H>::barbar(){
    // use the type H<T> here
};
```